# Bad characters/symbols when reading from an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm new to C and I'm trying to read a file and store it's contents into an array. I can do this just fine. Even tried to access the array's contents in the block where I set them and it shows me the data that I expect of it. 
However, in a different block, I have a for loop to retrieve the contents of the array but bad characters are printed on screen. What could be the problem?

```
 for(int j=0;j<valCount;j++){
            printf("%s\n", current_val[i].process_name);
        }
```

My output changes every time. Right now when I ran it, it is:
 `�mooG`�mooG `�mooG`�mooG`

However, when I use the same `printf` function on the block where I set the values to the array, I get the actual data that I need. What am I doing wrong in this second block?

Comment: Can you please paste the entire code snippet along with the first block of code *(to get an elaborated idea of the issue)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the entire block of code it's very difficult to help you solving your problem. The first thing which "looks suspicious" is that you actually don't use variable j in the for loop. Maybe that's the problem.